# Selecting a middle node in Tor using Stem

Tags: relays, python, stem, middle

I'm trying to learn my way around Tor and the Stem library for a class. My understanding is that the middle node is selected by tor and is unaccessible through Stem, however as part of the class I have to identify the middle node and find the address/location/etc.

After doing some research it looks like some suggest to go about doing this using extend_circuit, while others say that it's just not doable (which i'm assuming is incorrect since if it wasn't doable it wouldn't be part of the class?). I was hoping for some help/direction so I know where to look and how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`stem.control.Controller.get_circuits`](https://stem.torproject.org/api/control.html#stem.control.Controller.get_circuits) returns a list of [`stem.response.events.CircuitEvent`](https://stem.torproject.org/api/response.html#stem.response.events.CircuitEvent).

Each of these contains a `path` attribute, which is a list of the relays involved in the circuit, including the middle relay.

Comment: So, just to double check i'm understanding this correctly, if the output looks something like (('jsdasld', 'C'), ('sjdfls', 'a'), ('sdfsdf', 'W')), then these are the entry, middle, and exit nodes?

Comment: right, or at least the order of the nodes. not all circuits exit the tor network.

Comment: You say you want to "select" a middle relay, this shows what middle relay is in use in current circuits if you're looking to build custom circuits with your own chosen middle node, then see this: https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/12401/iterate-through-list-of-exitnodes/12408#12408